# WPF Bind to Nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Using an MVVM approach and MVVMLight Toolkit, I am implementing a WPF View to show values to each different Question of a Test.  Each Question has a Question Number and it also has 2 words.  One word is called a Prompt, the other is called a Target.  See below for my Models.  The Models look more complicated than they should be for this question, however there are more parts to the test that I will implement later on that require the models to be this way.

### WmtTest

- List<WmtQ> Qs

### WmtQ //Questions

- QNum, //Question Number
- Dictionary<QItemType, QItem> Items

### WmtQItem

- string Name
- Image Image

### enum QItemType

- Prompt,
- Target,
- etc

I am trying to bind the Prompt in one column and the Target in a second column in a Grid.  However, I can't figure out how to bind from the List<WmtQ>'s down to the nested Prompt and Target values from the Items Dictionary.  Note that I was able to bind to the Question Number successfully in its own column (just for testing purposes).  Let me know if you need more information.  Thanks.

### Here's my View

```
<UserControl x:Class="ApuntaNotas.Views.WmtListView"
         DataContext="{Binding WmtList, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding WmtQs}" x:Key="WmtQsVS">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <ComponentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WmtQsVS}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentWmtQ}" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding QNum}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Items["Prompt"].Value???}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Items["Target"].Value???}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

### Here's my ViewModel

```
    public class WmtListViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    private IWmtQRepository _wmtQRepository;
    private ObservableCollection<WmtQ> _wmtQs;
    private List<Guid> _wmtQIds;
    private WmtQ _currentWmtQ;       

    public WmtListViewModel(IWmtQRepository wmtQRepository)
    {


        _wmtQRepository = wmtQRepository;

        WmtQs = new ObservableCollection<WmtQ>(_wmtQRepository.FindAll());


        if (WmtQs.Count >= 0)
            CurrentWmtQ = _wmtQs[0];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the current wmtQ.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The current wmtQ.</value>
    public WmtQ CurrentWmtQ
    {
        get { return _currentWmtQ; }
        set
        {
            _currentWmtQ = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentWmtQ");
        }
    }


    public IWmtQRepository WmtQRepository
    {
        get { return _wmtQRepository; }
        set
        {
            _wmtQRepository = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("WmtQRepository");
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the wmtQs list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The wmtQs list.</value>
    public ObservableCollection<WmtQ> WmtQs
    {
        get { return _wmtQs; }
        set
        {
            _wmtQs = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("WmtQs");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the wmtQ ids.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The wmtQ ids.</value>
    public List<Guid> WmtQIds
    {
        get { return _wmtQIds; }
        set
        {
            _wmtQIds = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("WmtQIds");
        }
    }

}
```

### Edit: Here's My Models

```
[Serializable]
public class Q : Notifier
{
    private Guid _id;
    private int _qNum;
    private Dictionary<QItemType, QItem> _wmtIRQItemsDictionary;

    public Q(int qNum)
    {
        _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _qNum = qNum;
        _wmtIRQItemsDictionary = new Dictionary<QItemType, QItem>();
    }

    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        private set
        {
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    public int QNum
    {
        get { return _qNum; }
        set
        {
            _qNum = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("QNum");
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<QItemType, QItem> QItemsDictionary
    {
        get { return _wmtIRQItemsDictionary; }
        set
        {
            _wmtIRQItemsDictionary = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("QItemsDictionary");
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
            return false;

        var other = obj as Q;
        return other != null && other.Id == Id && other.QNum == QNum;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return QNum.ToString();
    }
}


public enum QItemType
{
    Prompt,
    Target,
    Bizarre,
    Foil,
    TFoil,
    DFoil,
    TDFoil,
    Extra1,
    Extra2,
    None
}


[Serializable]
public class QItem : Notifier
{
    private Guid _id;
    private string _item;
    //private QItemType _qItemType;

    public QItem() : this(string.Empty)
    {
    }

    public QItem (string item)
    {
        _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _item = item;
        //_qItemType = qItemType;
    }

    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        private set
        {
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    public string Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set
        {
            _item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
            return false;

        var other = obj as QItem;
        return other != null && other.Id == Id && other.Item == Item;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Item;
    }
}
```

Comment: *nested dictionary* No, no, you already had me at *dictionary*. Bindings do *not* play well with Dictionaries.  I would strongly suggest you create custom collections using the KeyedCollection<K,V> as a base class. You can then implement INotifyCollectionChanged on the collection and INPC on the collection kv pairs.  Those work very well with bindings.

Comment: @Will I agree that *dynamic* bindings don't play well but his ListView is bound to a StaticResource so in this case it should be ok.

Comment: @MarkFeldman It's not just change notification. The design of dictionaries don't work well at all with bindings. Static resources or not, it doesn't matter.  Better to stay far away from them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner quotation marks, just do it like this:

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Items[Prompt].Value}"/>
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Items[Target].Value}"/>
```

If that doesn't work then you'll need to post the code for your models (notably QItem).

Comment: I couldn't get those to work.. I added my models in the original post.  Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to provide a [complete, minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the code you've posted still has large parts either missing or irrelevant i.e. IWmtQRepository, WmtQ, Notifier etc.

Comment: It will take some time to get a minimal example ready, so I'm not sure if I will get to it.  I believe I have a workaround figured out though.